# How can I automatically change the Android's version string to -dev when in development mode?

Tags: android, gradle

I would like build`.gradle` and the build to automatically append `-dev` to a version string when in development. 
For instance,

- `1.0.2-dev instead of 1.0.2...`

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Or set versionNameSuffix for a build type conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing in a gradle property (stored in a file) or by passing in as a system property.

Look at section 11.2 of the Gradle documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Which states:

> 11.2. Gradle properties and system properties
>   Gradle offers a variety of ways to add properties to your build. With the -D command line option you can pass a system property to the JVM which runs Gradle. The -D option of the gradle command has the same effect as the -D option of the java command.
>
> You can also add properties to your project objects using properties files. You can place a gradle.properties file in the Gradle user home directory (defined by the “GRADLE_USER_HOME” environment variable, which if not set defaults to USER_HOME/.gradle) or in your project directory. For multi-project builds you can place gradle.properties files in any subproject directory. The properties set in a gradle.properties file can be accessed via the project object. The properties file in the user's home directory has precedence over property files in the project directories.
>
> You can also add properties directly to your project object via the -P command line option.
>
> Gradle can also set project properties when it sees specially-named system properties or environment variables. This feature is very useful when you don't have admin rights to a continuous integration server and you need to set property values that should not be easily visible, typically for security reasons. In that situation, you can't use the -P option, and you can't change the system-level configuration files. The correct strategy is to change the configuration of your continuous integration build job, adding an environment variable setting that matches an expected pattern. This won't be visible to normal users on the system. [4]
>
> If the environment variable name looks like ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_prop=somevalue, then Gradle will set a prop property on your project object, with the value of somevalue. Gradle also supports this for system properties, but with a different naming pattern, which looks like org.gradle.project.prop.
>
> You can also set system properties in the gradle.properties file. If a property name in such a file has the prefix “systemProp.”, like “systemProp.propName”, then the property and its value will be set as a system property, without the prefix. In a multi project build, “systemProp.” properties set in any project except the root will be ignored. That is, only the root project's gradle.properties file will be checked for properties that begin with the “systemProp.” prefix.

Example 11.1. Setting properties with a gradle.properties file

```
gradle.properties
    gradlePropertiesProp=gradlePropertiesValue
    sysProp=shouldBeOverWrittenBySysProp
    envProjectProp=shouldBeOverWrittenByEnvProp
    systemProp.system=systemValue

build.gradle
    task printProps << {
        println commandLineProjectProp
        println gradlePropertiesProp
        println systemProjectProp
        println envProjectProp
        println System.properties['system']
    }
```

Output of gradle:

```
gradle -q -PcommandLineProjectProp=commandLineProjectPropValue -Dorg.gradle.project.systemProjectProp=systemPropertyValue printProps

commandLineProjectPropValue
gradlePropertiesValue
systemPropertyValue
envPropertyValue
systemValue
```